# "[FATAL] [DBT-10503]" Invalid template file specified

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, silent-installer

Trying to install 12.2.0.1 Oracle database as Container Database.
While running command

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase -responseFile /scratch/orainst/12201/response/cpq_dbca.rsp
```

I get this error:

> "[FATAL] [DBT-10503]" Invalid template file specified

I am using the "General_Purpose.dbc" in the dbca.rsp

Answer (score 1):

You should use 
**templateName=General_Purpose.dbc**
in your */scratch/orainst/12201/response/cpq_dbca.rsp*
or add 
 **-templateName General_Purpose.dbc**
in your command.
For example, my dbca.rsp is

```
responseFileVersion=/oracle/assistants/rspfmt_dbca_response_schema_v12.2.0
gdbName=PROD
sid=PROD
databaseConfigType=SI
createAsContainerDatabase=false
templateName=General_Purpose.dbc
sysPassword=Welcome1
systemPassword=Welcome1 
emConfiguration=DBEXPRESS
emExpressPort=5500
dbsnmpPassword=Welcome1
characterSet=AL32UTF8
memoryPercentage=60
totalMemory=3000
```

If you create PDB database from response file you should use 18.1 version

Comment: I've encountered the same error as Anirban describes. I've used this example just changing gdbName, sid, passwords and memory parameters and it worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Linux/Unix Solaris, check the permissions set on the template file.

```
root@server $ chown oracle $ORACLE_HOME/assistant/dbca/templates/General_Purpose.dbc
root@server $ chmod 755 $ORACLE_HOME/assistant/dbca/templates/General_Purpose.dbc
```

or whatever custom template you might be using.
Try passing it as a parameter and not in the response file. Also try passing the -datafileJarLocation parameter

Answer (score 0):

We must use the below syntax:

```
templateName=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/db_1/assistants/dbca/templates/General_Purpose.dbc
```